# Android : PSS (Proportional Set Size) Calculation

Tags: android, memory-management

I am trying to figure out how the PSS is calculated is Android.

I found one [article](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0708.1/3930.html) that states the following.

> The "proportional set size" (PSS) of a process is the count of pages
>   it has in memory, where each page is divided by the number of
>   processes sharing it. So if a process has 1000 pages all to itself,
>   and 1000 shared with one other process, its PSS will be 1500

My first question is, is the above information accurate ? If not, could someone tell me how it is really calculated ?

Also, is this value is kilobytes or is "PSS" a unit by itself ?

Comment: This article helped me to understand what PSS is about: [Android Memory Management: Understanding App PSS](http://www.littleeye.co/blog/2013/06/11/android-memory-management-understanding-app-pss/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that information is accurate, and that's exactly how it is calculated. (The LWN.net article is [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/); note that Matt Mackall who participates in that thread you link to developed that feature.)

PSS is in kilobytes, like all the other information you get in `/proc/<pid>/smaps`. Its unit follows from how it is calculated.

([How often is PSS value updated for a given process in /proc/pid/smaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34189/how-often-is-pss-value-updated-for-a-given-process-in-proc-pid-smaps) has some pointers as to where and how PSS is calculated - disclaimer: I wrote the answer there. There are a few other posts on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) that discuss PSS and related metrics.)