# PSS/USS Linux-Android. Does Pss contain Uss?

Tags: linux, memory, process, uss

I would like to ask you:

I understand that on Linux, there are process that have shared libreries, and for look this, we can use PSS because this give information about the shared libraries size. And Uss is private dirty memory of a process.

But my question is:

Pss doesn't contains Uss, it's only about the proportionally shared memory;

or

Pss = Uss + proportionally shared memory.

Which interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this question was already answered here:

[Android : PSS (Proportional Set Size) Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070145/android-pss-proportional-set-size-calculation)

> The "proportional set size" (PSS) of a process is the count of pages
>   it has in memory, where each page is divided by the number of
>   processes sharing it. So if a process has 1000 pages all to itself,
>   and 1000 shared with one other process, its PSS will be 1500